# function to print any type in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm learning Lua for about a  week now and I've built (I hope) a function to print any type in Lua. As I'm new to Lua I don't quite understand:

- if there is a more succinct way to achieve this
- if there is a standard way to print nested tables
- if there are any cases the function doesn't cover

````
function printAnyLuaType(AnyLuaType, identationSpaces, identationLevel)

    function printTable(tableToPrint)
    --recursively print a table indenting
        for index, value in pairs(tableToPrint) do
            depperIdentation = currentIdentation .. identationToAppend
            if type(value) == 'table' then
                print(currentIdentation .. index)
                currentIdentation = depperIdentation
                printTable(value) --call to function
            else
                print(currentIdentation .. index)
                print(depperIdentation .. value)
            end
        end
        shallowerIdentation = string.sub(currentIdentation, 1, #currentIdentation - identationSpaces)
        currentIdentation = shallowerIdentation
    end

    --globals for printTable
    AnyLuaType = AnyLuaType or ''
    identationSpaces = identationSpaces or 4
    identationLevel = identationLevel or 0
    identationToAppend = string.rep(' ', identationSpaces)
    currentIdentation = string.rep(identationToAppend, identationLevel)

    --recursively printTable or normal print
    if type(AnyLuaType) == 'table' then
        printTable(AnyLuaType)
    else
        print(AnyLuaType)
    end
end

tableToPrint = {1234, {'a','b','c'}, 5678, ['complains'] = {'ugly', 'fragile'}, {['name'] = 'smith', ['age'] = 10}}

printAnyLuaType(tableToPrint)

--[[
expected output:

1
    1234
2
    1
        a
    2
        b
    3
        c
3
    5678
4
    age
        10
    name
        smith
complains
    1
        ugly
    2
        fragile
--]]
```
````

Comment: Beware the infinite loop. Also, globals are bad.

Comment: Indeed, an infinite loop is possible if you try to print a table `t` constructed by the following script: `t={}; t[1]=t; printAnyLuaType(t)`.  There is an [explanation](https://www.lua.org/pil/12.1.2.html) in the "PiL" book on how to process tables with cycles.

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't cover the case of cyclic tables,
but that's fine, we'll view that as out-of-scope.

The [style guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20230501071539/https://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide)
recommends that

> Variables holding values or objects are typically lowercase

This suggests naming the first parameter `anyLuaType` instead.

But it's not clear that "any lua type" is really the central
problem this code solves, so consider banishing that phrase
from identifiers, preferring to put it in explanatory `-- comments`.

You might instead simply name it `function display(value)`,
and document that value can be many things including a table.

Any recursive function will have a base case plus recursive
code that reduces the input problem to simpler problem(s).
Up in the mainline you check for type table, which seems
an odd place to put the check.
And then ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))
we need more checking within the function.

Consider expanding the
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
so the function is responsible for distinguishing the base case.
Also, rather that fix the "depper" typo,
introducing a brief indent helper would be convenient:

```
indentSpaces = 4

function indent(level)
    io.write(string.rep(' ', level * indentSpaces))
end

function display(value)
    displayRecursive(value, -1)
end

function displayRecursive(value, level)
    if type(value) ~= 'table' then
        indent(level + 1)
        return print(value)
    end

    for index, value in pairs(value) do
        displayRecursive(index, level)
        displayRecursive(value, level + 1)
    end
end
```

This appears to be a more succinct way of achieving your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

> if there is a more succinct way to achieve this

No.

> if there is a standard way to print nested tables

Your way is the standard way.

> if there are any cases the function doesn't cover

You can not distinguish between boolean value `true` and string`"true"`, the same for `nil`.

One more note:
Try to use local variables instead of globals (`currentIdentation`, `depperIdentation`).

Comment: While this is an acceptable answer, it is not a good answer. It would help if you provided more explanations.

Comment: @pacmaninbw - What exactly needs to be explained?